# Query on User object using org data

Tags: apex, community, batch

I'm attempting to test my batch job where I'm querying `Users` based on `JobGrade` and creating a custom record for each. For some reason, my test function keeps using org data instead of test data that I'm creating. I'm not using `SeeAllData=True` so I'm a little confused on why this is happening.

Then I keep getting the error `no more than one executebatch can be called from within a test method`

I attempted to delete all the `User` records but I can't use the `delete` operation on `User` objects. Any idea how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with [Setup data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm), you typically have to find a way to "inject" a fake query in order to limit the number of records the batch will process. That typically looks like this:

```
public class SomeBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
  @TestVisible String query = 'SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ...';
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }
  ...
```

Which you would then update in your unit test:

```
SomeBatch b = new SomeBatch();
b.query = 'SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ... LIMIT 200';
Test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch(b);
Test.stopTest();
// verify results
```

There are other methods you can use, as well, such as using the [Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm), which allows you to use dependency injection. However, in most cases, that's overkill, but if you had a standard framework for this, it would allow you to build compile-safe code, but there's a minimum overhead to make this work that wouldn't be worth it for a one-off situation.

Answer (score 1):

The users are available in your test because **the User object is a *setup object***. Some other objects are included on that list. You can see some of those in the [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm) 
 documentation.

The "more than one executebatch" error [can be caused by the fact that your method is trying to run for multiple users](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yqLIAQ). Assuming your batch class will process 200 records at once, for example, then your test should not handle more than 200 records. Otherwise **it will try to run the code exactly as a batch** (which means running twice or more, attempting to process all the 200+ records).